# iText7 - Html to PDF - Footer with page counter - How change color

Tags: java, html, itext, itext7, pdf-conversion

Using iText7 for Java, I try to convert a HTML into PDF.
I try to change the style of my footer, without success.

My HTML :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            #header {
                position: running(header);
                text-align: left;
                margin-top: 50pt;
                margin-left: 320pt;
                font-family: Garamond;
            }
            
            @page {
                margin-top: 200pt;
                margin-right: 30pt;
                margin-bottom: 50pt;
                margin-left: 30pt;
                
                @top-right {
                    content: element(header);
                }
               
                @bottom-center {
                    content: "Page " counter(page) " of " counter(pages);
                }

            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header">
            Monsieur Jay LAPOISSE<br>
            13 avenue de la Chance<br>
            35911 Rennes
        </div>
        
        <div style="page-break-after: always;">First page</div>
        <div style="page-break-after: always;">Second page</div>
        <div>Last page</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

My Java

```
try {
    HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(new FileInputStream(new File(SRC)), new FileOutputStream(new File(DEST)));
} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace(System.err);
}
```

My goal:

[image: the goal]

If I try to do as for the header, I don't arrive to have the page counter.

And if I do as my code above, I don't arrive to affect a style.

Comment: Hi, can you provide your current output and describe the desired result in more detail? I tried to convert your HTML to PDF but it's not clear to me what is wrong and what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Hi, I add a picture of my goal to my question. 
I try to have a footer with a defined style and a title part and a page counter part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS has 16 page margin areas in total where you can put your content. Your use case can be achieved by using those areas easily with the following CSS code:

```
@bottom-right {
    color: red;
    content: "Page " counter(page) " of " counter(pages);
}
@bottom-left {
    color: red;
    content: "[document title]";
}
```

Full HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    #header {
      position: running(header);
      text-align: left;
      margin-top: 50pt;
      margin-left: 320pt;
      font-family: Garamond;
    }

    @page {
      margin-top: 200pt;
      margin-right: 30pt;
      margin-bottom: 50pt;
      margin-left: 30pt;

      @top-right {
        content: element(header);
      }

      @bottom-right {
        color: red;
        content: "Page " counter(page) " of " counter(pages);
      }
      @bottom-left {
        color: red;
        content: "[document title]";
      }

    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
  Monsieur Jay LAPOISSE<br>
  13 avenue de la Chance<br>
  35911 Rennes
</div>

<div style="page-break-after: always;">First page</div>
<div style="page-break-after: always;">Second page</div>
<div>Last page</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Visual result after converting to PDF with pdfHTML 3.0.1:

[image: result]